# Why screen turns on while connecting/disconnecting charger?

Tags: charging, power-on

Even if it's (somehow) understandable to turn screen on while **connecting** charger, why it turns on also on **disconnecting**? Whats behind the design decision for this?

Is there native way of preventing this behaviour?

Comment: @Izzy I've checked developer options on different Android version from 4.0 to 7.0, never found an option to make screen stay off. My question is about reason behind this "feature", as I doubt it is useful in any way.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable it on settings, depending of your device and ROM.

Comment: It would be great if you were to provide some example screenshots of where the option can be found in the settings app in various ROMs.

Comment: Sorry, an overly generalized answer doesn't really help without any examples.